# Replacing a symbol or comma followed by any letter notepad++

Tags: notepad++

how do i do this in Notepad++?

i want to change this line:

> "James",Bond","Barry",Allan"

into:

> "James Bond","Barry Allan"

what do i put in "Find what"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `",(?=\w)`
- Replace with:   (a space)
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
",      : a double quote followed by a comma
(?=\w)  : lookahead, make sure we have a word character after the comma
```